# Convert .docx resource to pdf during maven build automatically

Tags: docx4j

We have a maven project that contains a number of .docx files that need to be released as .pdf. Currently, we generate .pdf from a source .docx file manually, but this is error-prone; already we have had a release that went out with a stale version of a .pdf because a developer failed to convert to .pdf after modifying the source .docx file.  To prevent similar snafu in future, I would like to perform .docx to .pdf conversion automatically during the maven build.  I have looked at various converters and like docx4j the best; the problem is that I can't find a way to automatically invoke it during a maven build of our project.

I am considering writing a maven plugin that can be invoked during the compile (or package) phase to automatically perform this docx-to-pdf conversion, but am hoping that someone here can point to an existing solution to this issue.

Comment: Not aware of anything specific; you could use exec-maven-plugin